# Нужна помощь с jQuery скриптом

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Никак не могу додумать как по повторному клику по блоку возвращать все это дело в исходное состояние.

Буду рад если кто-то подскажет, у меня явно какие то проблемы с логикой.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVQpgO

```
$('.block').on('click', function(){
    $('.block').find('.img-gap').fadeOut('300');
    $('.block').removeClass('active');
    $('.block').removeClass('deactive');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().addClass('deactive');
});

$('.block.active').on('click', function(){
    $('.block').find('.img-gap').fadeIn('300');
    $('.block').removeClass('active');
    $('.block').removeClass('deactive');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(.block.active)` - на момент присваивания обработчика событий, такого селектора нет, следовательно события не присвоится. в событие `click` класса `.block` проверяйте наличие класса `.active` у текущего элемента.

```js
$('.block').on('click', function(){
        $('.block').removeClass('deactive');
           
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
          $('.block').find('.img-gap').fadeIn('300');
          $('.block').removeClass('active');
        } else {
          $('.block').find('.img-gap').fadeOut('300');
          $('.block').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
          $(this).siblings().addClass('deactive');
        }
    });
```

```css
.block {
  height: 536px;
  width: 33.1%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  vertical-align: top;
  transition: 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 61px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.block .img-gap {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block .img-gap .img-gap__logo {
  margin: auto;
}

.block__text {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.1s;
  color: white;
  padding: 100px;
}

.block__title {
  display: inline-block;
}
.block__subtitle{
  display: block;
}
.block__more-btn {
  @include main-btn;
  max-width: 178px;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.block.active {
  width: 62%;
  transition: 1s;
}

.block.deactive {
  width: 18.7%;
}

.block.active .block__text {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="img-gap">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100/100" alt="" class="img-gap__logo">
  </div>


  <div class="block__text">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/100/100" alt="" class="img-gap__logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
        <h2 class="block__title">title</h2>
        <span class="block__subtitle">subtitle</span>

        <p class="block__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias harum, doloremque ratione asperiores laboriosam facere vitae. At facilis corrupti dolorem debitis, amet minus voluptatum fuga, voluptates nulla repellat nam quasi.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="block__more-btn">подробнее</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="img-gap">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100/100" alt="" class="img-gap__logo">
  </div>
  <div class="block__text">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/100/100" alt="" class="img-gap__logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
        <h2 class="block__title">title</h2>
        <span class="block__subtitle">subtitle</span>

        <p class="block__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias harum, doloremque ratione asperiores laboriosam facere vitae. At facilis corrupti dolorem debitis, amet minus voluptatum fuga, voluptates nulla repellat nam quasi.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="block__more-btn">подробнее</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="img-gap">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100/100" alt="" class="img-gap__logo">
  </div>
  <div class="block__text">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/100/100" alt="" class="img-gap__logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
        <h2 class="block__title">title</h2>
        <span class="block__subtitle">subtitle</span>

        <p class="block__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias harum, doloremque ratione asperiores laboriosam facere vitae. At facilis corrupti dolorem debitis, amet minus voluptatum fuga, voluptates nulla repellat nam quasi.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="block__more-btn">подробнее</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Хотите, можно так:

```
$('body').on('click', '.block', function(){
    $('.block').find('.img-gap').fadeOut('300');
    $('.block').removeClass('active');
    $('.block').removeClass('deactive');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().addClass('deactive');
});

$('body').on('click', '.block.active', function(){
    $('.block').find('.img-gap').fadeIn('300');
    $('.block').removeClass('active');
    $('.block').removeClass('deactive');
});
```